# Can't boot after booting into windows

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, windows-8, boot-repair

I recently installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 8. Then used Boot Repair and all was fine.The Grub boot loader showed-up and had an option to boot Ubuntu or Windows. Then I booted into windows. Everything looked fine until I rebooted. After I rebooted there was just a black screen with some text saying:

```
No boot device available 
SATA 0: Installed 
SATA 1: Installed 
SATA 2: None
SATA 3: None
Strike the F1 key to retry boot, F2 to run setup utility
```

When I hit the F2 key it takes me to the BIOS setup where i see that it is trying to use the Windows Boot Manager instead of the Ubuntu Boot Manager.

I am not sure what i can do here, if it is of any use i do have both a Ubuntu installation disk and a Windows installation disk. Oh and the Bootinfo link from running Boot Repair is http://paste.ubuntu.com/6536548/

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), but when asked "`Do you want to activate [Backup and rename Windows EFI files]?`", answer `No`.
Then in your BIOS (UEFI firmware), set `Ubuntu` as default entry.

Now using Windows should not mess up the boot any more.

Comment: So i will have to re-install Ubuntu so i can get to a terminal, and then run the Boot Repair command.

Comment: No, you just need to run Boot-repair from a live disk. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#Getting_Boot-Repair

Comment: I tried that, and it sort-of worked... Windows Boot Manager is still the only entry in the BIOS, but it works now.

Comment: Forgot to mention the Boot Info link. [Here it is](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6546659/).